# How to run my react app by manually adding vitejs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, vite

I am a beginner and learning react and using Vite as module bundler.

But instead of creating vite project, I am manually adding it.
In project directory *i ran node cmd* - **npm install vite @vite/plugin-react. And it created node modules folder and package.json and lock file.**

When i open using live server in vscode i get -
**index.jsx:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/jsx". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.**

From searching i found to include "start" :"..." in package.json but dont know what to include there. I tried ***"start": "node scripts/index.jsx"***
And when i open in node using npm run or npm start i get error =>

> **npm ERR! Missing script: "start"**
> :"..."  Lifecycle scripts included in undefined:
> start
> node /scripts/index.jsx

**and when i run npm start i get** =>

> Error: Cannot find module 'D:\scripts\index.jsx'
> at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: []

**MY index.jsx and index.html =>**

```js
import Header from "./scripts/Header.js";
const root= ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Page/>);   

function Page() {
    return(
        <div>
            <Header/>
            {/* <MainContent>
                <Card/>
            </MainContent>
            <Footer/> */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>A Minimal React App</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"> -->

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div> 
    <script src="scripts/index.jsx" type="module"></script>       
</body>
</html>
```

**MY package.json =>**

> {   "type": "module",
> "scripts": {
> "build": "vite build"   },
> "dependencies": {
> "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
> "vite": "^5.1.6"   }   }

Can anyone please help how to resolve this error and run the app?

Answer (score 0):

From what i get...you have an existing react project, created with CRA, and want to migrate to Vite, right?

With vite you dont need to use live server, and from what i see in you package.json file, you're missing the start command for vite.

Check this link for a [migration guide from cra to vite](https://coreui.io/blog/how-to-migrate-create-react-app-to-vite/)

I'm not sure about the error you posted, but i think that its a conflict of having react-scripts(from cra) and vite installed. Honestly...check the guide first and see if you did everything accordingly, 99% sure the error will disappear. Dont forget to run vite with the proper command as well :P

Have fun! :)

Answer (score 0):

install `vite.js` again with these orders. In your current folder, open  cmd and type:

```
npm create vite@latest
```

Choose `react.js` and then `javascript`

When installation is finished open up your `vscode` in that folder and install modules by command

```
npm i
```